# android service connection... Messenger or Binder or AIDL?

Tags: android

I am getting quite confused with different opinion from diff people and the developer sitee...

I am building an app in which i am having a service(local service) runnning... which keeps getting data updated (sockets).. i want this to get reflected in the activity each time...

which one is the most ideal way to follow ??

Comment: If your service is private to your own application and runs in the same process as the client, you should use Binder. The Messenger creates a queue of all the client requests in a single thread, so the service receives requests one at a time; If you want your service to handle multiple requests simultaneously, then you can use AIDL directly. In this case, your service must be thread-safe and capable of multi-threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think binder would be better, because messenger or aidl aims at cross-process communication.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Binder is not comparable with AIDL. They are totally different things. Binder is a IPC mechanism used in Android; while AIDL, as its name -- Android Interface Definition Language, is similar to other IDLs you might have worked with. AIDL allows you to define the programming interface that both the client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other using Binder.  App developers, however, do not use the Binder directly. Instead, they must define and  interact with interfaces using AIDL.

So, your question becomes "should I use Messager or Binder？"
-- My understanding is: Binder is used for inter-process communication; while Messager can be used for both inter and intra cases which do not require multi-threading. So it depends on the scenario you work on.

Comment: May I know why the binder is not comparable with AIDL? As you can see the 
 nicely explained comparison between AIDL, Binder and Messenger on the [Official Website](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl)

Answer (score -3):

I think binder and aidl are the same. You have to first create a `.aidl` file, then you have to bind that between activity and service. Then the `.aidl` file will work as an interface between activity and service.

Messenger is another way.